# How do I inject a png that is imported as string into div tag?

Tags: javascript, dom, png

I have a png file that I am using rollup to turn into a string (on the client) like this...

```
{
  input: pkg.entry,
  plugins: [
    resolve(),
    commonjs(),
    string({
      include: '**/*.(html|css|png|svg)',
    }),
    resolve(),
  ],
  output: {
    name: pkg.name,
    file: pkg.umd,
    format: 'umd',
  },
}
```

When I run it becomes a string and I am trying to inject it into an image tag using

```
import logo from './logo.png';
...
console.log(logo);
this.logo = `data:image/png;base64, ${logo}`;
this.refresh();
...
const html = Mustache.render(template, this);
...
<img src="{{logo}}" alt="Red dot" />
```

When I try to run I get the following error...

> GET data:image/png;base64, %EF%BF%BDPNG%0A%1A%0A%EF%BF%B... net::ERR_INVALID_URL

How do I render a png as a string?

Here is the string...

```
console.log(logo);
```

"�PNG\r\n\u001a\n\u0000\u0000\u0000\rIHDR\u0000\u0000\u0001�\u0000\u0000\u0000�\b\u0006\u0000\u0000\u0000L\u001d/�\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0019tEXtSoftware\u0000Adobe ImageReadyq�e<\u0000\u0000\u001e�IDATx���o\�y���[\u001f�(��[ ��Y8M�$t\u000b\u0004A\r�#�Y\u0006��d\u0017�õ\u0017\"�\u0002R��H\u0001��# �4\u0005�\u0006��-4Q` 0���\u0017��\"\u001e\u0015\rZ��H[�D����\u001d�+��|Ͻ���\u0001\u0006�e����y�y�5\u0006\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\nL�G\u0000Z\u0019�Zu.�RN>s��\u001a�y�o�:O\u0007\u0000\u0010p\u0000]�-�}5�T��l�o�I>���\u0006b\u000e\u0000\bx�\t��|���|�÷����\u0004���{��?;\u001eQ�\u001f��..."

Comment: It looks like your `data` part of the string is just binary data and not properly `base64` encoded string. Maybe try encoding it?

Comment: I tried encoding using btoa but it didn't work threw an error

Comment: If it was `Character Out Of Range` error try solutions mentioned in this article https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding#The_Unicode_Problem